# Is the MAC address stored in software or hardware?

Tags: hardware, hard-reset, mac-address

I'm trying out a ROM.  It seems to be flashing the whole system.  It claims it is a total wipe.

However, the MAC address seems to never change.  So my question is, is the mac address for an Android stored in the ROM or is stored somewhere in the hardware?

Comment: MAC addresses, and similar persistent information, are stored in a protected partition... They never change under normal flashing of ROMs or images..

Answer (score 2):

A media access control address (MAC address) of a computer is a unique identifier assigned to network interfaces for communications at the data link layer of a network segment. MAC addresses are used as a network address for most IEEE 802 network technologies, including Ethernet and Wi-Fi. Logically, MAC addresses are used in the media access control protocol sublayer of the OSI reference model.

MAC addresses are most often assigned by the manufacturer of a network interface controller (NIC) and are stored in its hardware, such as the card's read-only memory or some other firmware mechanism. If assigned by the manufacturer, a MAC address usually encodes the manufacturer's registered identification number and may be referred to as the burned-in address (BIA). It may also be known as an Ethernet hardware address (EHA), hardware address or physical address (not to be confused with a memory physical address). This can be contrasted to a programmed address, where the host device issues command to the NIC to use an arbitrary address.